# Run video from html5 Video tag in android

Tags: android, html

I want to use HTML5 support in android webview.
when I am trying to run html5 video in webview its not working as it is working in android web browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android's WebView provides many HTML5 features, such as  and geolocation, but those features are not enabled by default. Furthermore, some of the steps to enable those features.

Try this [Html5WebView](http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/)

it may help you.